# Is it possible to prevent mysql_real_escape_string from converting NULL to 0 with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-real-escape-string

Trying to insert as NULL if an input field is empty, using `PHP`.

I've got an `INT` field that defaults to `NULL`. This is for a hockey player to enter their jersey number.

If they don't have a jersey number, their "jersey" field should be null in my MySQL database. But when I `mysql_real_escape_string` the value (which is `$jersey = NULL`), it defaults to `zero`.

Do I have to change my field to a `VARCHAR`? Or is there a work around for `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Here is my insert code:

```
sprintf("INSERT INTO players (playerName, playerNumber,) 
VALUES 
('%s',%d,)",
mysql_real_escape_string($name),
mysql_real_escape_string($number)
```

Thanks for any insight. I couldn't find any answers when searching SO.

Comment: Why not check for null before using `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: Ya, that's not a bad idea.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() has nothing to do with malicious code

Answer (score 1):

It is not  mysql_real_escape_string issue at all.

But rather the way you are creating your query.

For the old mysql extension the only way is to add a literal `NULL` instead of a variable.

```
$name = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
$number = is_null($number) ? 'NULL' : intval($number);
$sql = "INSERT INTO players (playerName, playerNumber) VALUES ($name, $number)";
```

Or, if you want to get rid of the mess, use [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO players (playerName, playerNumber) VALUES (?s, ?i)";
$sd->query($sql, $name, $number);
```

As after very convincing request I've finally made translation from PHP nulls to query nulls.
And it will be shortest code of all the proposed solutions.

Comment: I've edited my original message to include how I'm inserting the values. Is this not a proper way anymore?

Comment: I am from the moon. Please don't tell anyone. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yet I see no reason for flagging my comment. It meant no harm anyone

Answer (score 1):

```
sprintf("INSERT INTO players (playerName, playerNumber) VALUES (%s, %s)",
  is_null($name)   ? 'NULL' : "'".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'"
  is_null($number) ? 'NULL' : "'".mysql_real_escape_string($number)."'"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that would work as well. I realize now I don't need to escape my value at all.

Comment: Even if you think you don't need to do it, please do escape all values that you glue to SQL. Or better yet use PDO to connect to SQL and prepared statements with '?' placeholders.

Comment: Wow, that is way more advanced than I'm used to. I didn't realize my technique was so out of date.

Comment: this still inserts as 0. I think it's sprintf that's automatically forcing it to be an int, instead of just NULL.

Comment: Sheesh. I should've seen that.

Comment: @Jon %d in `sprintf` would force it to be int. %s is a string. It should work. If it doesn't, it means that your `$number` variable doesn't contain actual php NULL, but some other special value (maybe FALSE?). Please do `var_dump($number);` to see what's actually in that variable when you expect it to be NULL.